# How to select an arbitrary MP3 as ringtone on LineageOS?

Tags: lineageos, ringtone

I encoded a part of a song as MP3 and I'd like to set it as ringtone on LineageOS 14. I found some instructions to move the file to a certain location - or better locations because the locations because they seem to differ based on model and version. However, it's 2018 and developers are usually educated in basic UX, so there's probably an acceptable way to do this (assuming that it's not acceptable to force a user to speculate that a configuration option might be available after moving a file to a certain unspecified location in the context of a GUI - [forum threads like this one of a German LineageOS forum not based on meritocratic swarm intelligence suggest five contradictory approaches](https://www.lineage-os-forum.de/Thread-CM-MP3-als-Klingelton)).

I'm using LineageOS 14.1 on a Moto G 2014.

Comment: Moving it to `Ringtones` under internal storage always did the trick, and it's simple enough for me. The folders have been fixed since Android 5 (the OS will spawn these folders by default under internal storage if they don't exist).

Comment: @AndyYan Notice that the directories are automatically spawned only after a factory reset, though (not that one can't just create them by hand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this damaged my profile setup so that I needed to do a factory reset. The approach is however supposed to work and most likely will with your phone - have a backup ready just in case and see https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-one/help/lineage-os-homescreen-menu-buttons-t3553235 for (horrible forum-style) info in case you don't and and did the following anyway.

Since I don't have access to the internal storage in the LineageOS and other file browsers, but to my SD card only (or the SD card is commonly referred to as internal storage which would be largely ambiguous), I could put the MP3 file into `Ringtones` on the SD card and select the ringtone **after a reboot**.

I suggested to replace this with an intuitive import function in the ringtone selection menu at https://jira.lineageos.org/browse/BUGBASH-1945.